# How to clear diagnostic logs on Azure Web Apps when using the Local Cache feature?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm currently hosting a ASP.NET MVC Web app on Azure's App Service offering and have optionally opted into use their [App Service Local Cache feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview#how-local-cache-changes-the-behavior-of-app-service) since my app does not need to write to the local file system.

This has improved the performance of my web app but I've come to realise that it fills up the local File System very quickly when a file system despite having the app setting `"WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS": "2"` with a quota of 99MB (not sure why I can't see this in AppSettings?) set on `App > Diagnostic Logs` area.

[The documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview#how-local-cache-changes-the-behavior-of-app-service) it does modify the way logfiles are stored but doesn't mention how to remove them.

> - Web apps can continue to write log files and diagnostic data as they    do currently. Log files and data, however, are stored locally
>     on the    VM. Then they are copied over periodically to the shared
>     content    store. The copy to the shared content store is a best-case 
>     effort--write backs could be lost due to a sudden crash of a VM
>     instance.
> - There is a change in the folder structure of the LogFiles and Data    folders for web apps that use Local Cache. There are now subfolders
>     in the storage LogFiles and Data folders that follow the naming
>     pattern of "unique identifier" + time stamp. Each of the subfolders
>     corresponds to a VM instance where the web app is running or has run.

This has been confirmed by by a quick Powershell command on the Kudu Console on the `D:\home\logfiles` directory.

```
PS D:\home\logfiles> Get-ChildItem | Sort LastWriteTime
Get-ChildItem | Sort LastWriteTime


Mode                LastWriteTime   Name              
----                -------------   --------------------------
d-----       11/28/2017   1:52 AM   http                          
d-----       11/28/2017   4:42 AM   kudu                          
d-----       11/28/2017   4:46 AM   SiteExtensions                
d-----        12/1/2017   1:26 AM   Application                   
d-----        12/1/2017   1:26 AM   Monaco                        
d-----         3/7/2018   3:37 PM   5198ab_18_03_03_06_28_59      
d-----         3/7/2018   4:03 PM   907c1a_18_03_06_06_44_22      
d-----         3/8/2018   3:59 PM   5198ab_18_03_07_14_25_08      
d-----         3/8/2018   3:59 PM   ff0fc5_18_03_07_11_46_16      
d-----         3/8/2018   4:02 PM   0c1a69_18_03_07_08_14_26      
d-----         3/8/2018   4:03 PM   a9316b_18_03_08_04_25_31            
d-----         3/9/2018   4:02 PM   5e5ff2_18_03_08_08_44_41      
d-----         3/9/2018   4:02 PM   c87157_18_03_09_03_50_23      
d-----        3/10/2018   6:18 AM   0c1a69_18_03_09_18_29_49      
d-----        3/10/2018  10:32 AM   1440de_18_03_09_11_09_37
... <Excluded for brevity>
... <Excluded for brevity>      
d-----        7/31/2018  12:33 PM   fe780a_18_07_30_03_36_41      
d-----        7/31/2018   4:02 PM   f713f0_18_07_31_04_13_17      
d-----        7/31/2018   4:03 PM   2a1ef5_18_07_30_23_18_41      
d-----         8/1/2018   4:17 PM   7254a1_18_07_31_08_14_27      
d-----         8/1/2018   4:18 PM   c01540_18_08_01_02_17_00      
d-----         8/1/2018   4:18 PM   bcecd7_18_07_31_09_41_33      
d-----         8/1/2018   4:18 PM   11e825_18_07_31_16_28_38      
d-----         8/2/2018   6:18 AM   2ee8db_18_08_01_17_19_18      
d-----         8/2/2018   6:18 AM   6ba224_18_08_01_04_13_34      
d-----         8/2/2018  10:33 AM   dca085_18_08_01_04_14_00      
d-----         8/2/2018  10:33 AM   6ead4a_18_08_01_11_08_46      
d-----         8/2/2018  12:32 PM   4c87a3_18_08_02_00_07_21      
d-----         8/2/2018  12:33 PM   faf4de_18_07_28_16_57_44      
d-----         8/2/2018   4:21 PM   46b00f_18_07_31_23_36_35      
d-----         8/2/2018   4:21 PM   52a38c_18_08_01_11_02_26      
d-----         8/3/2018  12:33 PM   bcecd7_18_08_01_07_50_23      
d-----         8/3/2018   4:02 PM   8eac1e_18_08_03_02_32_24      
d-----         8/5/2018   2:35 PM   2341b7_18_08_03_04_15_08      
d-----         8/6/2018  12:16 AM   0d1e3e_18_08_02_09_30_34      
d-----         8/6/2018  12:17 AM   540bec_18_08_01_10_02_30      
d-----         8/6/2018  11:04 AM   3952e0_18_08_05_20_58_56      
d-----         8/6/2018  11:59 AM   NewRelic
```

My Environment settings are

```
"WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION" : "Always"
"WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB" : "1800"
"WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS": "2"
"WEBSITE_LOCALCACHE_READY": "TRUE"
```

So the questions are

1) How do I remove periodically remove the `"unique identifier" + time stamp` folders e.g. `3952e0_18_08_05_20_58_56`?

2) How can I make it respect my diagnostic settings e.g. Retention of 2 days with a maximum quota of 99MB?